# How to copy multiple row in table while inserting additional value

Tags: mysql

How can i copy table and insert new value at the same time

I want to copy a table with multiple rows and insert a same value `"Borrowed"` for one column `Transaction`. I already know how to copy but i dont know how to copy and insert new/another value at the same time.

here is what i got:

```
INSERT INTO TRANSACTION(UserID,TRANSACTION,First_Name,Last_Name,ISBN,Title,DATE) 
VALUES (1,"Borrowed",(SELECT First_Name,Last_Name,ISBN,Title),NOW());
```

Comment: Create a procedure that will copy the table and after the table is copied insert the record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your fixed values into the SELECT list:

```
INSERT INTO TRANSACTION(UserID,TRANSACTION,First_Name,Last_Name,ISBN,Title,DATE) 
    SELECT 1, "Borrowed", First_Name,Last_Name,ISBN,Title,NOW()
    FROM <your table goes here>
```